# my camera wont stay on my character anymore.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
/// <summary>
 /// Description of class#
 /// </summary>
[RequireComponent (typeof (BarsEffect))]
public class ThirdPersonCameraz : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
/// <summary>
/// The distance away from the character.
/// </summary>
private float distanceAway;
[SerializeField]
/// <summary>
/// The distance up away from the camera.
/// </summary>
private float distanceUp;
[SerializeField]
/// <summary>
/// How long it will take for the camera to go from one place, to where we are trying to place the camera.
/// </summary>
private float smooth;
[SerializeField]
/// <summary>
/// The reason that the follow is a transform is because the characters position is going to be updated using physics
/// calculations. since the character has a rigid body on him, the physics are a fixed update which is bad because it
/// doesnt get updated as often.
/// </summary>
private Transform followXForm;

private float widescreen = 0.2f;
private float targetingTime = 0.5f;


private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f,1.5f, 0f);

private Vector3 lookDir;
/// <summary>
/// target position is where we will be trying to position the camera.
/// </summary>
private Vector3 targetPosition;

private BarsEffect barEffect;
private CamStates camState=CamStates.Behind;

private Vector3 velocityCamSmooth= Vector3.zero;

private float camSmoothDampTime = 0.1f;
public enum CamStates
{
    Behind,
    FirstPerson,
    Target,
    Free
}



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    ///this will grab the Follow game object which is tagged as a player
    followXForm = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
    lookDir = followXForm.forward;

    barEffect = GetComponent<BarsEffect> ();
    if (barEffect == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Attach a widescreen BarsEffect script to the camera.", this);
                       }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


void OnDrawGizmos()
{
}
/// <summary>
/// this function is good for making a camera because after you position all your objects
/// you can put ur camera code here and it will make sure everything lines up properly since it happens 
/// after update.
/// </summary>
void LateUpdate()
{
    // distance from the characters follow to the height.
    Vector3 characterOffset = followXForm.position + new Vector3 (0f, distanceUp, 0f);

    //determines the camera state
    //calculates the direction from camera to player, kill y and normalize to give a valid direction with unit magnitude.
    //
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Target") > 0.01f) {
                    barEffect.coverage = Mathf.SmoothStep (barEffect.coverage, widescreen, targetingTime);
                    camState = CamStates.Target;
            }
    else {
                    barEffect.coverage = Mathf.SmoothStep (barEffect.coverage, 0f, targetingTime);
                    camState = CamStates.Behind;
            }

    switch(camState)
    {
    case CamStates.Behind:
    ///setting the target position, were taking the Follow position and moving it up by a distance, and moving
    /// back by distance away based on the follow vector.
    /// Vector.up will always be (0,1,0)


    ///drawing the characters position to the up vector we created.
    Debug.DrawRay (followXForm.position, Vector3.up * distanceUp, Color.red);
    /// Drawing the characters position based on the away distance
    Debug.DrawRay(followXForm.position,-1f*followXForm.forward*distanceAway,Color.blue);
    lookDir = characterOffset - this.transform.position;
    lookDir.y = 0;
    lookDir.Normalize ();
    Debug.DrawRay (this.transform.position, lookDir, Color.green);
    targetPosition = characterOffset + followXForm.up * distanceUp - lookDir * distanceAway;
    ///drawing a line from the follow position to the target position.
    Debug.DrawRay(followXForm.position, targetPosition,Color.magenta);
        break;
    case CamStates.Target:
        lookDir=followXForm.forward;



        break;
        }
    targetPosition = characterOffset = followXForm.up * distanceUp - lookDir * distanceAway;



    CompensateForWalls (characterOffset, ref targetPosition);
    ///making a smooth transition between its current position and the position it wants to be in
    /// delta time is the time between frames. delta time * smooth is normalizing the camera between frames.
    smoothPosition(this.transform.position, targetPosition);

    ///make sure the camera is looking at the character/follow(gameobject)
    transform.LookAt(followXForm);

}
private void smoothPosition (Vector3 fromPos, Vector3 toPos)
{
    this.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (fromPos, toPos, ref velocityCamSmooth, camSmoothDampTime);
} 
private void CompensateForWalls(Vector3 fromObject, ref Vector3 toTarget)
{
            Debug.DrawLine (fromObject, toTarget, Color.cyan);
            //compensate for walls between cameraz
            RaycastHit wallHit = new RaycastHit ();
    if (Physics.Linecast (fromObject, toTarget, out wallHit)) 
    {
                    Debug.DrawRay (wallHit.point, Vector3.left, Color.red);
                    toTarget = new Vector3 (wallHit.point.x, toTarget.y, wallHit.point.z);
            }
    }
```

}

ok so whats going on here is that after inputting
        break;
        case CamStates.Target:
        lookDir=followXForm.forward;

```
    break;
    }
targetPosition = characterOffset = followXForm.up * distanceUp - lookDir *distanceAway;
```

my camera no longer stays on the character.  The program is made so that when i push down on the left trigger it is supposed to follow the character, but when im not holding it down, the camera is free and the character can run around the camera.  im confused why it wont work.  I was following a unity third person controller and would appreciate any amount of help i can get! thanks!

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this

Comment: @Pyritie not really, this question can be solved here.

Comment: I cbf reading through your code but have you placed a log statement after the "break" to see if it is getting past the break? I don't know what is before the break but you may be exiting the method prior to the next lines being called.